# Why do I keep getting an error saying e in endtime is invalid syntax in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import time as t
t = t.time
starttime = t
def calcprod():
    prod = 1
    for i in range(1, 1000000):
        prod = prod * i
p = calcprod()
print("The result is %s digits" % (str(len(p))))
endtime = t
print("It took %s seconds to calculate" % (starttime - endtime))
```

I don't know how I can fix my code.

Comment: Is the backtick at the beginning a typo when you paste the source code to StackOverflow or that actually lied on the source code? Other than that I don't see any syntactical errors, what is the exact 'invalid syntax' report you got (either from a REPL or IDE,...)?

Comment: Yes, Stackflow seems to put backticks at the beginning and end of my question and code. I don't know why.

Comment: There's no SyntaxError here. What there is is 1) An error in calling `len(p)` because `p` is `None` (you don't return anything from the function `calcprod`, even if you did return `prod`, it's an `int` that has no len) and 2) An error in performing `starttime - endtime` because you assign both of the these to the *function* `time.time` and *not* to the result of *calling* the function `time` (i.e `t()`)

Comment: Here is what the terminal is showing: `File "Time.py", line 10
    endtime = t
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: To continue with @JimFasarakisHilliard's list 3) `str(len(p))` should be `len(str(p))`, your intent is probably to get the *length* of characters from the *string* representation of `p`, what you did is reversed and will be runtime error.

Comment: @Codebek Try to delete the whole line then retype it to clear out any weird invisible characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you find some hopefully useful comments to solve your problems:

```
import time as t
t = t.time    # Don't name this the same as your time library
              # Also use t.time() instead of t.time
starttime = t
def calcprod():
    prod = 1
    for i in range(1, 1000000):
        prod = prod * i
        # return a value here (hint: cast the result to a string)
p = calcprod()
print("The result is %s digits" % (str(len(p))))
endtime = t    # This assigns the same value to 'endtime' as starttime.
               # You need to measure the current time again.
               # How can you do this?
print("It took %s seconds to calculate" % (starttime - endtime))
                # Does it make sense to calculate starttime-endtime?
                # Which one is the bigger value?
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the return statement in your function maybe this is the problem